# How can I convert GMT date to system date format?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I have a Date : 2019-07-18 00:30:32 GMT+10:00.

I want to convert string to date but its gives wrong date.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local;
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current;

let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
```

Its gives wrong date : **"Jul 17, 2019 at 8:00 PM"**

Comment: That's not the wrong result. It's correct. You must be in the GMT+5:30 timezone, right?

Comment: Unrelated but do not use `NSTimeZone` and `NSLocale` in Swift. Use `TimeZone` and `Locale`. Also note that setting the formatter's timezone is pointless in this case because the string you are parsing provides its own timezone.

Answer (score 0):

> When working with fixed format dates, such as RFC 3339, you set the
>   dateFormat property to specify a format string. For most fixed
>   formats, you should also set the locale property to a POSIX locale
>   ("en_US_POSIX"), and set the timeZone property to UTC.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Reference : [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

I seen it shows correct date, It is based on your **Time zone**:
[image]

Check with :
https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: While setting this special locale is a good idea, it has nothing to do with what is posted in the question. And setting the formatter's timezone is pointless when parsing a string that provides its own timezone.